# Boost wave context concept_check issue

Tags: c++, boost

I'm debugging with concept check in boost and gcc. The code finds are error like this

```
/home/hoffman34/boostlibsinstall64/include/boost/wave/util/
cpp_iterator.hpp:2495:1:   instantiated from

'boost::wave::pp_iterator<boost::wave::context<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, 
std::basic_string<char> >, 
boost::wave::cpplexer::lex_iterator<boost::wave::cpplexer::lex_token<> >, 
boost::wave::iteration_context_policies::load_file_to_string, 
advanced_preprocessing_hooks> >'
../../../../ROSE/src/frontend/SageIII/attachPreprocessingInfo.C:408:34:   instantiated 
from here
/nfs/apps/gcc/4.5.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.5.0/../../../../include
/c++/4.5.0/bits/boost_concept_check.h:209:7: error: using invalid field 
'__gnu_cxx::_SGIAssignableConcept<_Tp>::__a'
make[6]: *** [attachPreprocessingInfo.lo] Error 1
```

It refers me to this line

```
context_type::iterator_type first = ctx.begin();
context_type::iterator_type last  = ctx.end();
```

408 is the first line there, but 409 is so similar I imagine it will have the same issue.

context_type is defined as such

```
typedef boost::wave::context<std::string::iterator, lex_iterator_type, 
boost::wave::iteration_context_policies::load_file_to_string, 
advanced_preprocessing_hooks > context_type;
```

iterator_type is supposed to be part of context. Does anyone know Boost::Wave enough to know what this means?

Comment: I would look at cpp_iterator.hpp to try to figure out exactly which type it thinks is unassignable.

Comment: will give that a shot, and edit the post if necessary!

Comment: I don't think its the cpp part, the boost concept check is checking there for an assignment and a copy operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a known issue (see Boost ticket [#1079](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/1079)), but not in Wave but in Spirit's (V1.x) parse tree generation code. The concept checking complains about an incomplete type.

This error only pops up when compiling Wave using gcc and with --enable-concept-checks or #define _GLIBCXX_CONCEPT_CHECKS 1.

Comment: THANK YOU! This was driving me crazy. OK, now I have to figure out how to get around it.